# Disable database session for some endpoints

Tags: php, laravel, session, disable

I have sass aplication using many databases depends of subdomain.
Application use session with driver base on database.
When I use one database I want to disable session on some endpoint, but I don't know how to do it.
I fount article with `Route::filter`([here](https://dor.ky/laravel-prevent-sessions-for-routes-via-a-filter/)) but I use Laravel 5.7.

To do this I need make new provider and change session driver?
Or is better way to do this? I'm not working on API.

Comment: change the session driver to what?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write it. Change database driver to array driver?